# VS2015 typescript cordova add as a link

Tags: cordova, typescript, visual-studio-2015

There is no option on VS2015 to add a file as a link on a Typescript Cordova project. How to do it ?

I tried to edit the .jsproj by adding this :

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\TypeScriptHTMLApp1\Core\**\*.*">
      <Link>Views\Core\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

but it's not working at all.

The goal is to have this file hierarchy :

- Typescript HTML Core files
- C# Web project (which use Core files)
- Cordova project (which use Core files)

For the C# web project, it's ok. But for the cordova project, can't add my core files as a link...

How I can do that ?
Thanks

Edit: I have found a workaround :

Put this on the .jsproj

```
<!-- On build, we copy all core front end files -->
  <Target Name="CopyContentFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesToCopy Include="path to your shared folder on the core project\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)"
             DestinationFiles="@(FilesToCopy->'path to your shared folder on the destination project (cordova project), for eg: www\core\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
             SkipUnchangedFiles="True" />
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio at Microsoft.

Unfortunately, the Cordova project system does not support add as link. To prevent confusion, we removed the option in update 3.

There is no good workaround at the moment. The best solution is to copy files from one project into the other. I know this is a pain. We are discussing solutions that will enable easier code sharing in the future, but at the moment we don't have a good answer for you.

Thank you for this valuable feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have edited my question by adding my current workaround...